# No objects detected with Google MLKit on iOS

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-mlkit, react-native-vision-camera

I am new to Google MLKit and want to detect bills/receipts for Android and iOS.
I use [Object Detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection) and [this model](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/object_detection/mobile_object_labeler_v1/1).

Detection is done by Google MLkit and then interpreted by [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera)

On android in `java` I have no problem, the bills are well detected :

[Image](https://wololofit.com/myu2.gif)

On iOS and for identical code (but in `Objective C` instead of `Java`), I never have an invoice detected :

[Image](https://wololofit.com/myu.gif)

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <VisionCamera/FrameProcessorPlugin.h>
#import <VisionCamera/Frame.h>
#import <MLKit.h>

@interface VisionScanObjectsFrameProcessorPlugin : NSObject
+ (MLKObjectDetector*) objectDetector;
@end

@implementation VisionScanObjectsFrameProcessorPlugin

+ (MLKObjectDetector*) objectDetector {
  static MLKObjectDetector* objectDetector = nil;
  if (objectDetector == nil) {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lite-model_object_detection_mobile_object_labeler_v1_1" ofType:@"tflite"];
    MLKLocalModel *localModel = [[MLKLocalModel alloc] initWithPath:path];

    MLKCustomObjectDetectorOptions *options = [[MLKCustomObjectDetectorOptions alloc] initWithLocalModel:localModel];
    options.detectorMode = MLKObjectDetectorModeSingleImage;
    options.shouldEnableClassification = YES;
    options.classificationConfidenceThreshold = @(0.5);
    options.maxPerObjectLabelCount = 3;

    objectDetector = [MLKObjectDetector objectDetectorWithOptions:options];
  }

  return objectDetector;
}

static inline id scanObjects(Frame* frame, NSArray* arguments) {
  MLKVisionImage *image = [[MLKVisionImage alloc] initWithBuffer:frame.buffer];
  image.orientation = frame.orientation; // <-- TODO: is mirrored?

  NSError* error;
  NSArray<MLKObject*>* objects = [[VisionScanObjectsFrameProcessorPlugin objectDetector] resultsInImage:image error:&error];

  NSLog(@"Object detected : %ld", objects.count);

  NSMutableArray* results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:objects.count];
  for (MLKObject* object in objects) {
    NSMutableArray* labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:object.labels.count];

    for (MLKObjectLabel* label in object.labels) {
      if (122 == label.index || 188 == label.index || 288 == label.index || 325 == label.index || 357 == label.index || 370 == label.index || 480 == label.index || 510 == label.index || 551 == label.index) {
        [labels addObject:@{
          @"index": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:label.index],
          @"label": label.text,
          @"confidence": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:label.confidence]
        }];
      }
    }

    if (labels.count != 0) {
      [results addObject:@{
        @"width": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:object.frame.size.width],
        @"height": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:object.frame.size.height],
        @"top": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:object.frame.origin.y],
        @"left": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:object.frame.origin.x],
        @"frameRotation": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:frame.orientation],
        @"labels": labels
      }];
    }
  }

  return results;
}

VISION_EXPORT_FRAME_PROCESSOR(scanObjects)

@end
```

I really think this code works because I don't have any crashes (I did before it worked ^^), but I never have a document detected. :/

`NSLog(@"Object detected : %ld", objects.count);` almost always `return 0`. **Exceptionally it will `return 1`** on detect my computer keyboard but this is very very very rare.

I've tried a lot of things in the last 4 days ([different model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/efficientnet/lite0/uint8/2), [asynchronous detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/ios#4_create_and_run_the_object_detector), resize before detection, etc.) but it's still the same :/

Comment: Hey! Have you found a solution for this problem? I have the same problem! :/

Comment: I just posted the solution to my problem  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jaroslaw K., I had to reduce the frame size to make it work.

This was recommended in the documentation of my model (https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/lite0/classification/2) :

> For this module, the size of the input image is flexible, but it would be best to match the model training input, which is height x width = 224 x 224 pixels for this model. The input images are expected to have color values in the range [0,1], following the common image input conventions.

```
public static func resizeFrameToUiimage(frame: Frame) -> UIImage! {
  let targetSize = CGSize(width: 224.0, height: 224.0)

  let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(frame.buffer)!
  let ciimage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
  
  let context = CIContext(options: nil)
  let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciimage, from: ciimage.extent)!
  let uiimage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

  let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / uiimage.size.width
  let heightRatio = targetSize.height / uiimage.size.height
      
  var newSize: CGSize
  if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
    newSize = CGSize(width: uiimage.size.width * heightRatio, height: uiimage.size.height * heightRatio)
  } else {
    newSize = CGSize(width: uiimage.size.width * widthRatio, height: uiimage.size.height * widthRatio)
  }
      
  let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
      
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
  uiimage.draw(in: rect)

  let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  return newImage
}
```